# How to compare two lists of same length (but different data types) and their corresponding values?

Tags: python, list, zip

I have two lists...

```
depth = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
direction = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x']
```

I want to compare the two of these lists and for each instance of direction == 'x', continually add the corresponding values in depth together. So I should get a value of 4 since 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 and it corresponds to each 'x' string in list direction.

The lists depth and direction are greatly abbreviated for example purposes. I want to iterate over both lists and in reality they contain a couple thousand values each.

I have already created a zip() and tried working with it like this:

```
dndzip = zip(depth, direction)
x = 0
for i,j in dndzip:
    if i == 'x':
        x += j
return x

print(x)
```

I actually had this for loop under a defined function, but unfortunately this for loop doesn't return the proper value. I get a value and no errors, but it's always a value of 2 and not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting 2 exactly, as when I ran the above code I got 0. But the reason for that is because in your loop, when you're decompressing your list with

```py
dndzip = zip(depth, direction)
for i,j in dndzip:
```

notice that you zipped your list with depth as the first argument, so in this case i is depth and j is direction, so x+=j is never run because i (depth) is never 'x'. To fix this, you would do:

```py
dndzip = zip(depth, direction)
x = 0
for j,i in dndzip:
    if i == 'x':
        x += j

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular code, it looks like you have the `i` and `j` mixed up. When you do `dndzip = zip(depth, direction)`, `dndzip` is going to contain tuples where the first item is the item from `depth`, and the second is the one from `direction`. Meaning that something like

```py
def sum_x_depths(depth, direction):
    dndzip = zip(depth, direction)
    x = 0
    for i,j in dndzip:
        if i == 'x':
            x += j
    return x
```

will fail, since things like `if i == 'x':` are comparing `i`, which is an `int`, to `'x'` which is a `str`. Then `x += i` also fails, because `j` is a `str` and `x` is an `int`. Make sure to try and make variable names refer to what they represent!

```py
def sum_x_depths(depths, directions):
    s = 0
    for depth, direction in zip(depths, directions):
        if direction == 'x':
            s += depth
    return s
```

You can also use the `sum` function and generator comprehensions to nice effect here, though it might be a bit long on a single line with these names:

```py
def sum_x_depths(depths, directions):
    return sum(depth for depth, direction in zip(depths, directions) if direction == 'x')
```